# Spotfire change datetime column to monday of weekday

Tags: datetime, powerbi, spotfire

im using spotfire software and i have a datetime column like:

| DateTime |
| --- |
| 21/07/2022 12:11:01 |
| 21/07/2022 14:32:01 |
| 04/12/2022 10:22:01 |
| 30/06/2022 16:22:01 |

how can i created a new calculated column where it instead changes the date to the monday of the week for all values?

many thanks

i can do this in power bi by dropping the time and using the function

```
Start of Week Monday = 'Data'[DateTime ]+1-WEEKDAY('Data'[DateTime ]-1)
```

this results in all the values changing to the monday of its given week/month/year

how can i do this in spotfire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following functions available to you: DateAdd, DayOfWeek (*)

You could try:

```
DateAdd("dd",1 - (If(DayOfWeek([original_Date])=0,7,DayOfWeek([original_Date]))),[original_Date])
```

This resets the date (including the time portion) to the *previous* Monday.

Initially I had tried the simpler formula:

```
DateAdd("dd",1 - DayOfWeek([original_Date]),[original_Date])
```

but Sunday is mapped to a zero, so whenever the original day was a Sunday, it was pushed to the *following* Monday.
It does depend on your original settings so you may have to play around with the numbers a bit.

(*) depending on what the source of your data is, equivalent functions may be available.